# Drawing multiple shapes with ShapeDrawable in xml with Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes

I am currently drawing a number of circles on a canvas in a custom view in code. the circles are static and do not change. I would like to draw them using a ShapeDrawable in xml to help clean up my code. I will have a number of different drawables which the user can select and therefore I don't want to do this in code. having 3 or 4 xml drawables seems a lot neater to me.

I have created one circle in xml using a ShapeDrawable but am unable to add more than one shape to the xml.

How do I add multiple shapes to an xml document using ShapeDrawable.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to add multiple shapes to my xml file using Layer-list.
I havent tried this yet but this seems t be exactly what I want as the shapes will be draw in the order of their array index.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
      <shape>
         <solid android:color="#FFF8F8F8" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:top="23px">
      <shape>
         <solid android:color="#FFE7E7E8" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

[Blog post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=9)

[Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Answer (score 103):

Here's how I did a filled red circle with a one-pixel black border, with a white number 72 in the middle:

Create an XML file in res\drawable and name it appropriately, eg red_circle_black_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then, to use it in your layout, declare it as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:text="72"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/red_circle_black_border" 
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Obviously, change the textSize and layout_width/height as required :-)

Comment: I assume you can use an imageview if you have no text to show?

Comment: Sure. It's in effect just a drawable now, so use it like an image.

Comment: Note you can achieve the same effect by using the stroke (AKA border) element of a shape:                                                                                         <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>

Answer (score 0):

I have an example check mark icon with 2 oral outsize may help you, put this in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#5265FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="38dp"
        android:height="38dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#636DFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="28dp"
        android:height="28dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <vector
            android:width="27dp"
            android:height="27dp"
            android:tint="#F3F1FE"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
            <path
                android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
                android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z" />
        </vector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```