# Drawing polygons in XML with Android

Tags: android, xml, polygon

I was looking for a way to draw a polygon, specifically a triangle, for an Android app.

I read about creating an XML file and using it in a layout for certain shapes with ShapeDrawable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061159/drawing-multiple-shapes-with-shapedrawable-in-xml-with-android), but as far as I know that only works for rectangles, ovals and rings.

I know that it's possible to draw a polygon with Path and PathShape programmatically, or to do so with OpenGL, or to draw a .png in Photoshop, but I'd much prefer a way to create one in my XML layout. Would it be possible to create a custom component to do this, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can extend [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and [add custom XML attributes](http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/) to the subclass that will construct a Path using [`lineTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#lineTo%28float,%20float%29). The points of the polygon can be specified as a array reference.