# Drawing a shape with a curve line

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes

Whant to draw as in this image [image]

for that would use as in the link ShapeDrawable [Drawing multiple shapes with ShapeDrawable in xml with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061159/drawing-multiple-shapes-with-shapedrawable-in-xml-with-android) but don't know how to make the line curve 
---------------------edit-----------------------------------

based on @Bojan Kseneman answer tried with the following code

```
    PointF pt1l = new PointF(canvas.getWidth()/2+40, (float)newPosY-canvas.getWidth()/40);//canvas.getWidth()/40
    PointF pt2l = new PointF(canvas.getWidth()/2+40, (float)newPosY+canvas.getWidth()/40);
    PointF midl = new PointF(canvas.getWidth()/2+30, (float)newPosY+canvas.getWidth()/40);

    PointF pt1r = new PointF(canvas.getWidth()/2-40, (float)newPosY-canvas.getWidth()/40);
    PointF pt2r = new PointF(canvas.getWidth()/2-40, (float)newPosY+canvas.getWidth()/40);
    PointF midr = new PointF(canvas.getWidth()/2-30, (float)newPosY+(canvas.getWidth()/40)/2);

    Path pathLeft = new Path();
    //pathLeft.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    pathLeft.moveTo(pt1l.x,pt1l.y);
    pathLeft.quadTo(midl.x,midl.y,pt2l.x,pt2l.y);

    Path pathRight = new Path();
    //pathRight.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    pathRight.moveTo(pt1r.x,pt1r.y);
    pathRight.quadTo(midr.x,midr.y,pt2r.x,pt2r.y);
    Paint curveLineR = new Paint();
    curveLineR.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    Paint curveLineL = new Paint();
    curveLineL.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    Paint circle = new Paint();
    circle.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    canvas.drawPath(pathLeft, curveLineL);
    canvas.drawPath(pathRight, curveLineR);
    //canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/30,circle);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,(float)newPosY,canvas.getWidth()/40,circle);
```

but didn't get a curve line more like parte of a circle(changing the value of midr and midl got closer but still was't quite a line). Maybe with a bit of more tests could get the line but for now only need the circle, for anyone that also trying to get the curve line leaving the code and +1 for @Bojan Kseneman for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a custom View and draw stuff like that with the Canvas. You have to draw two paths (two curves) and a circle in the middle. Here is the basic idea, you will have to do the rest of the work on your own.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 super.onDraw(canvas);
 Path pathLeft = new Path();
 pathLeft.moveTo(x1, y1);
 pathLeft.quadTo(x1, y1, x2, y2);

 Path pathRight = new Path();
 pathLeft.moveTo(x1, y1);
 pathLeft.quadTo(x1, y1, x2, y2);

 canvas.drawPath(pathLeft, mPathPaint);
 canvas.drawPath(pathRight, mPathPaint);
 canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint); 
}
```